# Top, Left, Right, Bottom Image combination Imagemagick

Tags: php, imagick

see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88XVW.jpg

I cut out images automatically and then want to add them in this manner, so they are basically forming the former photo but with borders in between. Can someone tell me how this works? I did use this:

```
    convert image.jpg -frame 5 -background none \
   ( uploads/left-crop.jpg ) -gravity west   -geometry  +0+30 -composite \
   ( uploads/middle-crop.jpg ) -gravity center -geometry +0+30 -composite \
   ( uploads/top-crop.jpg ) -gravity north -geometry 0,0 -composite \
   ( uploads/bottom-crop.jpg ) -gravity south -geometry 0,0 -composite \
   ( uploads/right-crop.jpg ) -gravity east   -geometry  +0+30 -composite \
output.jpg
```

But this doesn't really get me there.

Has anyone an idea, how I can do this?

Comment: How did you crop them? What is the image you are linking to - is it how it currently looks? Or how it is supposed to look? That image doesn't go back together to make a rectangle, does it? What are you trying to achieve?